# Java array list in class with tickets

Tags: java

I've to implement Ticket class in java.
This is my code:

```
public class Ticket {

private String name;
private Float defaultPrice;
private Event event;
private static ArrayList<Ticket> ticketList;

public Ticket(String name, Float defaultPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
}

public ArrayList<Ticket> getAllTickets() {
    return ticketList;
}
```

And my main problem is that how to do that creating an instance of Ticket class, ticketList has the newly created Ticket object. Because later I've to use public getAllTickets() method to get all tickets.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a bit weird this model: Ticket has a list of Tickets?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add the ticket to the list in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I've made it with uml diagram. So how can I add to this list all products I'll create ?

Comment: I'd say stop fussing around with UML tools and read the API docs for `ArrayList`.

Comment: I've to use this array list in this way. So how can I later iterate through whole tickets list using a method getAllTickets() ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I will have to just answer.
Do you mean that you need each ticket to be stored in the list whenever one is created?

If so make the constructor private and provide a factory method.

Like so:

```
public class Ticket {

private String name;
private Float defaultPrice;
private Event event;
private static ArrayList<Ticket> ticketList;

static {
    ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
}

private Ticket(String name, Float defaultPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
}

public static ArrayList<Ticket> getAllTickets() {
    return ticketList;
}`

public static Ticket getInstance(String name, Float defaultPrice)
{
    Ticket temp = new Ticket(name, defaultPrice);
    ticketList.add(temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I thought he wanted something similar to this as well..... The GetAllTickets bit implied that this is supposed to be a singleton or factory of some type, or at the very least that particular method and its backing collection was static. +1

Answer (score 1):

Complete example:

```
    package stackoverflow;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    public class Ticket {

        private String     name;
        private BigDecimal defaultPrice;

        public Ticket(String name, BigDecimal defaultPrice) {
            this.name = name;
            this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name =

 name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDefaultPrice() {
        return defaultPrice;
    }

    public void setDefaultPrice(BigDecimal defaultPrice) {
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
    }
}
```

Event class:

```
package stackoverflow;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Event {

    private Date         date;
    private List<Ticket> ticketList;

    public Event(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
        this.ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addTicket(Ticket ticket) {
        this.ticketList.add(ticket);
    }

    public List<Ticket> getTicketList() {
        return this.ticketList;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package stackoverflow;


import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Event eventX = new Event(new Date());

        eventX.addTicket(new Ticket("ticket1", new BigDecimal(50)));
        eventX.addTicket(new Ticket("ticket2", new BigDecimal(50)));
        eventX.addTicket(new Ticket("ticket3", new BigDecimal(50)));
        eventX.addTicket(new Ticket("ticketPremium", new BigDecimal(100)));

        for (Ticket ticket: eventX.getTicketList()) {
            System.out.println("name:" + ticket.getName() + " price: " + ticket.getDefaultPrice());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please private message

Comment: yep, send me message on alexandre.strevenski@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
If you are trying to make sure every new ticket adds itself to its own list of tickets, this can easily be taken care of in the constructor:

```
public Ticket(String name, Float defaultPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
    this.ticketList = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
    this.ticketList.add(this);
}
```

**Option 2**
You could also have a separate class method to add tickets to the list, and instead use that when you initialize a new ticket. For example your `Ticket` class would have the following:

```
public void addTicketToList(Ticket ticket){
    this.ticketList.add(ticket);
}
```

Then, when you create a new ticket you can use this:

```
Ticket newTicket = new Ticket();
newTicket.addTicketToList(newTicket);
```